# Access outer class object from inner class in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read similar questions on SO, but couldn't find answer.

This question is **not** about accessing **instance** of outer class or it's method, but about accessing outer **class object** that should be normal task. As soon as we have `__qualname__` that contains information about outer class's name, there is no reason why not to be able dynamically access to outer class object.

This example do job:

```
class Outer:
    class Inner:
        @classmethod
        def parent_class(cls):
            outer_name = cls.__qualname__.split('.')[-2]
            outer_cls = globals()[outer_name]
            print(outer_cls)


Outer.Inner.parent_class()  # <class '__main__.Outer'>
```

But it wouldn't work in `parent_class` function placed in another module:

```
# some.py
class Some:
    @classmethod
    def parent_class(cls):
        outer_name = cls.__qualname__.split('.')[-2]
        outer_cls = globals()[outer_name]
        print(outer_cls)

# main.py
from some import Some


class Outer:
    class Inner(Some):
        pass

Outer.Inner.parent_class()  # KeyError: 'Outer'
```

I think it can be solved with Outer's class decorator that appends it's class object to all nested classes, but is there any "clean" way just to get outer class object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this solution works in every case:

```
import sys


class Outer:
    class Inner:
        @classmethod
        def parent_class(cls):
            outer_name = cls.__qualname__.split('.')[-2]
            outer_module = sys.modules[cls.__module__]
            outer_cls = vars(outer_module)[outer_name]
            print(outer_cls)


Outer.Inner.parent_class()  # <class '__main__.Outer'>
```